# Got "request failed" while trying to post on facebook's wall

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using facebook connect with SSO to sign in/up users to my app, and want to ask user to post on wall after each login.

But, at the requestListener's onComplete (Post on wall dialog was shown, and user touched on Share), I'm getting a false response. Didn't find out what it means in the FB SDK docs, but anything was posted on my Wall. Response was supposed to return a JSON formated string, so when trying to execute "message = json.getString("message");", I get a FacebookError witch just prints "request failed"...

logcat:

```
07-27 12:58:09.170: W/FacebookConnect(26086): Activity Started
07-27 12:58:12.300: W/FacebookConnect(26086): User authorized
07-27 12:58:12.300: E/FacebookConnect(26086): onComplete called at facebook.authorize
07-27 12:58:12.300: E/FacebookConnect(26086): Access Token: AAAC1sJLmgzkBAD0M40SQLgluPU...
07-27 12:58:12.860: D/webviewglue(26086): nativeDestroy view: 0x223888
07-27 12:58:13.420: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(26086): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27701 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/androidhive.dashboard/databases/webview.db
07-27 12:58:13.420: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(26086): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27701 - "" errno=2 path=/CachedGeoposition.db, db=/data/data/androidhive.dashboard/databases/webview.db
07-27 12:58:14.670: D/SampleRequestListener(26086): Response: {"id":"1123123","name"...
07-27 12:58:14.680: E/FacebookConnect(26086): JSON {"work":[{"position"...
07-27 12:58:17.150: E/SampleDialogListener(26086): Dialog Success! post_id=1003157...
07-27 12:58:17.720: E/WallPostRequestListener(26086): Got response: false
07-27 12:58:17.720: E/WallPostRequestListener(26086): Facebook Error: request failed
```

My code (Error occurs in class WallPostRequestListener):

```
public class FacebookConnectActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG_JSON = "json";
static Facebook facebook = new Facebook("11111111111111");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
JSONObject json;
Context ctx = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resgatar_produto_layout);
    Log.w("FacebookConnect", "Activity Started");

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"email", "user_photos", "user_birthday", "user_hometown", "user_relationships","user_location", "user_work_history", "publish_actions"}, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.w("FacebookConnect", "User authorized");
            Log.e("FacebookConnect", "onComplete called at facebook.authorize");
            Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Access Token: "+facebook.getAccessToken().toString());
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("link", "www.qranio.com");
            facebook.dialog(ctx, "feed", params, new SampleDialogListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.w("FacebookConnect", "Error authorizing: "+error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}   
    });

    }

}

public static  void logoutFB(){
    if(facebook.isSessionValid()){
        facebook.setAccessToken(null);
    }
}

public void startDataProcess(){

    Intent a = new Intent(FacebookConnectActivity.this, FacebookDataProcess.class);
    a.putExtra(TAG_JSON, json.toString());
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}





public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
        if (postId != null) {
            Log.e("SampleDialogListener", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
            mAsyncRunner.request(postId, new WallPostRequestListener());
        } else {
            Log.e("SampleDialogListener", "No wall post made"); //Usuario clicou em Cancelar
            startDataProcess();
        }
    }

    public void onCancel(){ //Usuario clicou no X do dialog
        Log.w("FacebookConnect", "Post to Wall Canceled");
        startDataProcess();
    }
}

public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {

        Log.e("WallPostRequestListener", "Got response: " + response);
        String message = "<empty>";
        try {
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            message = json.getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("WallPostRequestListener", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.e("WallPostRequestListener", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Erro ao postar no Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        //startDataProcess();
    }
}


public class SampleRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {

            // process the response here: executed in background thread
            Log.d("SampleRequestListener", "Response: " + response.toString());
            json = Util.parseJson(response);
            Log.e("FacebookConnect", "JSON " + json.toString());

            //startDataProcess();

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new SampleRequestListener());
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("link", "www.qranio.com");
        //params.putString("display", "touch");
        facebook.dialog(ctx, "feed", params, new SampleDialogListener());
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Authentication authorizeCallback called (onActivityResult)");
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Access Token: "+facebook.getAccessToken().toString());
        //facebook.
        //if (facebook.isSessionValid()){

        //}else{
            //Log.e("FacebookConnect", "Invalid facebook session while trying to fetch user data");
        //}*/

    }catch(FacebookError fbe){
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "onActivityResult FacebookError " + fbe.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("FacebookConnect", "onActivityResult Exception " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is WallPostRequestListener useless? I've just removed is from SampleDialogListener.onComplete and it worked well...